# How to display server side error message in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display error message in wordpress style, i am getting the error message in plain text only. This is what i have tried

```
if ( isset( $_POST['user_old_password'] ) && $_POST['user_old_password'] ) {
    $current_user = get_userdata( $user_id );
    if ( !wp_check_password( $_POST['user_old_password'], $current_user->data->user_pass, $current_user->ID ) ) {
        echo "wrong password";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "wordpress style" ? At the moment you are just splitting plain text. To have this "wrong password" message looking good you can add some class like this echo '<h4 class="alert alert-danger">  . $message_here . '</h4>' ". And then add some css to this.

Comment: yes, i know how to add style sheet with a string but my query is in case of success message our url is like www.something,com?status=success i dont want this i want www.something.com in url and want to show the error message in top of the page like so many frame work doing (cakephp etc)

Comment: I will need you to provide more code examples, just by this i cant tell